# Add pause: "hover" to existing js

Tags: javascript

New here so forgive any blunders. I've searched stackoverflow but cannot find a way to add pause on hover to an existing script I got from W3Schools, can anyone tell me how? This is the code I'm using:

```
<script>
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  myIndex++;
  if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
  x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  setTimeout(carousel, 3000);

}
</script>
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>flytipping</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<h2 class="w3-center">Flytipping_5</h2>

<div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:70%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="1.JPG" style="width:100%" alt="">
  <img class="mySlides" src="2.JPG" style="width:100%" alt="">
  <img class="mySlides" src="3.JPG" style="width:100%" alt="">

</div>

<script>
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  myIndex++;
  if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
  x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  setTimeout(carousel, 3000);

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share your html?

Comment: html added to original post. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

In your HTML file:

```
<div class="mySlides" onhover="myFunction" />
```

In your JS file:

```
function myFunction() {
  ... do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable in your script. Set it to true on element hover, and in your function check if that variable is true then don't move your image. But you must unset this variable on mouse out.

Something like this:

```html
<div onmouseover="stopCarousel()" onmouseout="startCarousel()"></div>
```

```js
var doCarousel = true;
function stopCarousel() {
  doCarousel=false;
}

function startCarousel() {
  doCarousel=true;
}

function carousel() {
  if(!doCarousel) return;

  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  myIndex++;
  if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
  x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  setTimeout(carousel, 3000);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the timeout-id in a variable and call `window.clearTimeout(...)` on it like

```
<script>
       var myIndex = 0;
       var timeout;
       carousel();
    
       function carousel() {
           var i;
           var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
           for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
               x[i].style.display = "none";
           }
           myIndex++;
           if (myIndex > x.length) {
               myIndex = 1
           }
           x[myIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
           timeout = setTimeout(carousel, 3000);
    
       }
    
    
       function stopCarousel() {
           window.clearTimeout(timeout);
       }
</script>
```

Of course you need to call the `stopCarousel`-function on the event you like the carousel to stop.